# A completely different site load under my domain while my main site is working fine

Tags: wordpress, dns, cross-domain

I'm a real newbie in this world.

I just recovered from a serious attack, and I'm trying do things right at this time.

recently I made a quick Google search for my site and I found this page:

https://www.neocsatblog.info/CNC-Metalworking-&-Manufacturing-%C3%98-mm-for-Marble-Granite-Ceramic-Tile-312652-Woodworking-Supplies/

The problem is, my main site is a simple blog, so I do not sell anything, and obviously this link loads a completely different site from mine.

And this not the only suspicious site, which has link with my own domain while my main sites and pages loads on as usual.
Cloudflare shows many different links on firewall the request come from Russian federation, the strange thing is the other links what they trying to reach working to (Meanwhile I block all request from Russia, Singapore).

I don't understand this. I don't have this sites, on my ftp server, I don't have this site on my database.

Also I asked my hosting provider about this incident, they said my domain is registered and completely fine.

I'm using WordPress.
What's the next step?

How to remove this site from my domain?

I really would like to close all the backdoors.
Based on my inspections, I found the malware, which php code is this:
https://app.codingrooms.com/w/YgaXOdAllXsp
Its around 3000 lines, so I rather not paste in here, but you can view on the link.

Based on the code, do I need search more files on my ftp?

Comment: Your site is hacked. But this is not the place to seek advice for this. StackOverflow is a place where coders share and help with code. Questions asking for advice are off topic

Comment: @HowardE Which the perfect place where i can ask this if not webapps?

Comment: That I don't know. I just know that this type of question is not appropriate here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MrEbabi I added more information, I hope its help for clarifying the question

Comment: Update your Wordpress and theme (or downgrade and upgrade again) then install a security plugin to check your website. This is the shortest solution, if not works you should try malware detect websites.

Comment: @mrEabi My wordpress is clean now I found this outside wordpress in a subfloder. Now I would like to know based on php code, what I need to search on my main ftp directory, thats the real question

Comment: Consider searching on https://security.stackexchange.com/tour which is another site in the Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites.